# Is there a way to Sign in to two or more websites simultaneously

Tags: wordpress

A simple question. I have 2 wordpress websites, 1st is an e-commerce, 2nd will act as support ticket system. I want users to register on both sites, which I accomplished with "User Sync" plugin.

Another thing I wanted was if the user is logged into 1st website, when he switch to 2nd one, he should be logged in there too. like stack overflow works, or google network works, when I am logged in to Gmail, I am logged into youtube, gdrive, calendars, google search, etc.

How this "single sign in" or "sign in once" thing will work and with what plugin?

Comment: You can put a flag in website database is logged in set it to 1.When user a login to other website check this flag value.

Comment: You are talking about single sign on (SSO)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212483/how-to-transfer-login-information-and-automatically-log-to-another-website-when

Comment: Here is a tutorial to share logins with multiple website https://kinsta.com/blog/share-logins-wordpress/